# Gather funds from multiple wallets

Tags: transactions, ether, fees

I have many separate wallets thats all holds less or equal amount of ETH than average transaction fee.

Is there any way to collect those funds besides hoping a transaction with low fee will be included in block someday?

Answer (score 0):

A transaction is the cheapest interaction you can have with the Ethereum Blockchain. So it's your only hope to gather fund from multiple wallet.